# jQuery: Get `id` from the same class element

Tags: jquery

## Here is my code:

```
 <label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='".$row['id_control']."custom' ".(($row['status']=='1')?'checked':'')."value='1' class='js-switch modul_tabeli' />
 </label>
<table class='table' id='".$row['id_control']."'>
...
<table>
```

All elements is display in the while loop. I want to get the table `id`, when i click the checkbox.
Below is my jQuery code:

```
var test = $('.x_content').find('table');
var test2 = $(test).attr('id');
```

All script display 3 tables, but get only first table id.
Please help :)

I hope that make sense :)

Comment: x_content is a main div, where is label and table

Comment: can you show us how you are looping it?

Comment: sure:
`while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                extract($row);
                echo "<div class='x_panel'>
                    <label>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='".$row['id_control']."custom' ".(($row['status']=='1')?'checked':'')."value='1' class='js-switch modul_tabeli' />
                    </label>
</ul>
<div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
<div class='x_content' >
<table class='table table-bordered' id='".$row['id_control']."custom_table'>
...
<table>
}`

Comment: Please don't dump unformatted code blocks into comments where they are very difficult to read. Update the question itself with formatted code

Comment: Do you want table id when its associated checkbox is clicked or you want all table id?

Comment: Yes, i want table id, when someone click checkbox. Checkbox if before every tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery **Next** selector to get the next following table id when one of the checkbox is checked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-switch.modul_tabeli').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            var tableName = $(this).parent().next('table.table').attr('id');
        }      
    });
});
```

You can check this [Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davideoz/ageqLoyt/6/)

Comment: Thank, for response. I have jquery code:
`$('.modul_tabeli').click(function(){
    var test = $(this).attr('name');        
    var testId = (this.id);        
    var  ckbox_custom = $(".modul_tabeli");
    if (ckbox_custom.is(':checked')) {
        $('.isDisabled_custom').removeClass('isDisabled_custom').addClass('custom');
    var baza_custom_status = 1;
    } else {
            var tableName = $('table.table').attr('id');`

Comment: I have edited my answer.
You get the just the first value because using the .find('table') selector you target just the first one.
Using the .next('table') selector you will get the id of the following table if you have a checkbox before every table.

Comment: When i add `var tableName = $(this).next('table.table').attr('id');` now i have "undefined". Yes I have checkbox before every table

Comment: I have edited again my answer. Since the checkbox is inside a label tag, you have to target first the partent, and then use the next selector.

Comment: Tahnk you, no effect, still 'undefined' result

Comment: you can check the Jsfiddle, here you can see the behaviour.

Comment: Ok ;) In jsfiddle work well, but in my script not. Do you have any idea where can be problem?

Comment: In the code you past probably there is a mistake here:  
name='".$row['id_control']."custom' ".(($row['status']=='1')?'checked':'')."
you open the name attribute with one ' and you never close this apex

Comment: I deleted this code from my script, and stil undefined

Comment: It would be interesting if with Chrome you right click in the page and select the "View page Source", to check how is this code when is rendered in the browser.

Comment: I think that everything is good in page source. In the while loop i have short js code to edit table from bootstrap, but if i remove this code also not working

Comment: This is JS code to edittable from bootstrap
`<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'block';
$('#".$row_c['id']."opis').editable({
type: 'text',
pk: ".$row_c['id'].",                                  
url: 'tabelaProwizyjna/reg_tab_prow_kary_edit.php',
title: 'Opis'
});
$('#".$row_c['id']."custom').editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: ".$row_c['id'].",
    url: 'tabelaProwizyjna/reg_tab_prow_kary_edit.php',
    title: 'Wprowadź potrącenie'
});
</script>`

Comment: Ok, i understand, Thank you for Your help. I will try further.

Comment: If you are still struggling on that you can try with this code:
if(this.checked) {
            var tableName = $(this).parent().next('table.table').attr('id');
            $(this).addClass('test_1');
            $(this).parent().addClass('test_2');
            $(this).parent().next('table.table').addClass('test_3');
        } 

And then inspect the code to see if you find the classes. In this way you can see where you are missing your target

Comment: In this case, when i check checkbox then label has test_2 class, checkbox has test_1 class, but test_3 there is nowhere.

Comment: Ok, work! i have to add one more parent() and change html code. Thank You! ;)